# How different is a managed pointer from a borrowed pointer of infinite lifetime in Rust?

Tags: pointers, language-design, lifetime, rust

Rust uses *managed pointers*, written `@T`, which refer to an object on the heap that will be garbage collected.

It also uses *borrowed pointers*, written `&T` or `&lifetime/T`.

It seems to me that `@T` is in fact similar to a borrowed pointer, but with a special infinite lifetime.  Is that correct or are there some subtleties that I don't get yet?  If that is correct, why did the designers of Rust create a new type of pointer instead of introducing a magic lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert in Rust, just curious about it so don't count my answer as a final true.

As I understand a lifetime of burrowed pointer may not be defined, it can only be inferred. And the declaration `&lifetime/Pointer` only helps checker to decide what real pointer's lifetime it should use in lifetime analysis. So you cannot say that some your burrowed pointer has infinite lifetime, you can only use a lifetime that is already present.

I'd say burrowed pointers may be thought as weak pointers in other languages except that they are statically proved to always point to valid memory. So burrowed pointers with infinite lifetime wouldn't be the same as managed pointers because they don't own the object.

My source of information on this topic is: [Rust Borrowed Pointers Tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial-borrowed-ptr.html). Have you read it?

Answer (score 3):

**Foreword**: Rust is still under development, and the language has changed a lot since this question was answered.

For one, @ pointer is about to be removed from the languages, replaced by the [Gc](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/gc/index.html) and [Rc](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/rc/index.html) smart pointers, both provided by the standard library.

Second, the syntax for the lifetimes is now `&'a pointer`. The [References and Lifetimes Guide](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-lifetimes.html) is a comprehensive and well-written resource on the subject.

The content of my answer is still relevant if you take into account these two points.

---

In Rust, there are 3 way of allocating memory :

- On the stack (`T`). This is the same as in C.
- On the task's heap (`@T`). This memory is garbage collected, as in any GC'ed language.
- On the exchange heap (`~T`). The lifetime of this memory depends on who owns it.

Then, depending on the kind of allocation, you can hold a reference to a value using either a `@` pointer (only for `@`-allocated values), a `~` pointer (only for `~`-allocated values), a `&` pointer (borrowed pointer) or a `*` pointer (unsafe pointer).

```
let x: @int = @2;
```

In this example, the first `@` denotes the pointer type, whereas the second one indicates the allocation type. This is an `@`-pointer to a GC'd value.

```
let y: &int = @2;
```

This is a `&`-pointer to a GC'ed value.

`&`-pointers are useful, because they can reference any type of memory. When you write a function, you certainly want to declare the parameters as `&`-pointer, because the caller can then call the function with values allocated the way he wants. If your function declares a parameter as an `@`-pointer, then the caller has no choice but to pass it a heap allocated value.

`&`-pointers introduce the notion of lifetime. This is a notion used by the compiler to guarantee that these pointers will never outlive the allocated memory (thus making it "safe" pointers).

The "lifetime" of an `@`-allocated value is not known by the compiler : it is not determined statically by the compiler, but dynamically by the runtime.

Comment: Lifetime of managed @ pointer may be counted infinite because whenever you have @pointer it is always valid and alive.

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev would you mind posting an answer on the topic ? It is likely to be accepted ;)